# is there a function in kotlin that reads a file Char by char?

Tags: kotlin

Trying to read a file char by char in kotlin , i know you can read line by line in buffered reader. But to prevent huge chunks of data in ram if a file is all in on line i want to read char by char

Comment: You don't have to go to this extreme if you don't want to read a full line, you can also read a bunch of chars (but not a full line) into a buffer of some size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always just call `.read()` on a BufferedReader.  (It returns an int so it can return -1 if there's nothing, but otherwise you can convert the result to a char.)

Comment: @Loiis Wasserman You re saying that .read() returns ascii?

Comment: `Reader.read()` returns ASCII if the file is ASCII.  I recommend reading its documentation.